# How to perform division operator on struct?

Tags: c, structure

I have a struct containing three numbers: number1, number2, number3. Then, I want to perform division operators on them: (number1)/(number2+number3).

```
typedef struct {
    int number1;
    int number2;
    int number3;
    double ratio;
} table;
```

I tried to divide them like this:

```
for(int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
{
     for(int b = 0; b < 3; b++)
     {
     table[a][b].ratio = ((table[a][b].number1)/(table[a][b].number2 + data[a][b].number3));
     }
}
```

Should I divide structures using a repeated subtraction of dividend and divisor till the dividend becomes less than the divisor? Or is there any other approaches? I need to get double values, for example:

```
table[0][0].number1 = 1;
table[0][0].number2 = 2;
table[0][0].num3 = 3;
```

Then,

```
table[0][0].ration = 1/5=0.2
```

Comment: You need to make clear if you are looking for integer division or floating point division. Because either those call for different approaches.

Comment: your last paragraph makes no sense. What your code does seems to be *algorithmically* correct, just that you use integer division, which will probably not be what you want.

Comment: I am looking for floating point division

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems right. All that's missing is a casting to double before you do your division, something like:

```
table[a][b].ratio = ((double)(table[a][b].number1)) /
                    (table[a][b].number2 + data[a][b].number3);
```

If one of the operands is a floating point number in C, the division becomes a floating point division.

Comment: "If one of the operands is a floating point number in C, the division becomes a floating point division." Well that's a big over-simplification. `2.0 / 3 * 2` = 1.33 but `2 / 3 * 2.0` = 0.00. The sound practice, which should be the only acceptable professional practice, is to convert _all_ operands in the expression to `double` and _never_ mix integer and floating point in the same expression.

Comment: it's not an oversimplification, right? In `2/3*2.0`, the operands of the division are `2/3`. The `2.0` is an operand to another operation.

Comment: But which operands that ended up with which operator was based on precedence/associativity. Depending on the order, implicit type conversion of one integer operand or the other may happen before or after it ends up in an operation with the float operand. Any such expression with mixed types relying on implicit promotion and operator precedence both, is dangerous. Particularly during maintenance.

Comment: I do see your point, but I disagree. This expression is simple enough: single value in the numerator. And, the parentheses-fest that `((double)(table[a][b].number1)) /((double)(table[a][b].number2 + data[a][b].number3));`would be isn't any easier to read! To make matters even worse, `((double)(table[a][b].number1)) / (((double)table[a][b].number2) + ((double)(data[a][b].number3)));` does not yield the same result for sufficiently different-magnitude `number2` and `number3`.

Comment: (I'm aware I put more parentheses there than necessary, but I think your point was about unambiguity, and having to remember to what `(double)` binds specifically is worse than having to remember associativity of division, which every kind knows :) )

Comment: That would be a silly rewrite indeed. I posted an answer.

Comment: @Lundin Quote: "... the only acceptable professional practice, is to convert all operands in the expression to double" I have to disagree with this statement. Blindly putting a double-cast in front of all operands in an arithmetic expression may hurt performance and perhaps worse generate wrong results for some operand values. Instead split the expression into smaller parts and do the integer calculations first, i.e. avoid floating point calculations as long as possible.

Comment: @SupportUkraine I didn't say that the conversions should be done in the same expression. "Instead split the expression into smaller parts and do the integer calculations first" Well, maybe see the answer I posted to this question...

Comment: @Lundin well, that was how I read your comment... but maybe I just misunderstood it. And yes, your answer is actually doing exactly what I said.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the division so that the operands are floating point. It's generally not recommended to mix integers and floating point operands in the same expression without explicit casts. The inner `for` loop body should be rewritten as:

```
int sum = table[a][b].number2 + data[a][b].number3;
table[a][b].ratio = (double)table[a][b].number1 / (double)sum;
```

Comment: could as well just have declared the `sum` as `double`.

Comment: @MarcusMüller No, that way I would get implicit promotions in the code, which should be avoided.

Comment: Agreed, on a code level, the `=` would do an implicit promotion. But: Readability-wise, there is literally nothing implicit about writing `double sum = a + b`: the programmer very explicitly demands a double. In fact, I find it much easier to read than what you're doing there!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Coding standards like MISRA recommends to avoid that style, mostly because the sheer amount of beginners/intermediate level programmers who incorrectly believes `a + b` will get carried out on `double` type just because the result is assigned to one. Readability and safety don't always go hand in hand - the code written here is a reasonable compromise (and still MISRA compliant).

Comment: See, that' means I don't disagree with you personally – I just disagree with the notion that the the explicit casts within an expression are any easier to read, both for me, and for what I assume beginner coders feel.